# CSOM - Set specific permission on list item level

Tags: powershell, csom

I try to set specific permission on list items. I found some examples but I'm working in **Powershell** and I get a strange error

> The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Here's my code:

```
    foreach($item in $collListItem)
    {
        $srcContext.Load($item)
        $srcContext.ExecuteQuery()

        $item.BreakRoleInheritance($false, $false);

        $RoleDefBind  = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($srcContext)
        $PermissionLevel = $srcContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("Lecture")

        #userToAdd
        $user = $srcWeb.SiteUsers.GetByLoginName("i:0#.w|domain\test");
        $srcContext.Load($user)
        $srcContext.ExecuteQuery()

        $RoleDefBind.Add($PermissionLevel)

        $Assignments = $item.RoleAssignments
        $srcContext.Load($Assignments)
        $srcContext.ExecuteQuery()

        $item.Update()
        $srcContext.ExecuteQuery()
        $Assignments.Add($user,$RoleDefBind)
        $srcContext.Load($Assignments)
        $srcContext.ExecuteQuery()
    }
```

The error is always on the line `$Assignments.Add($user,$RoleDefBind)`

I added a lot of Load and ExecuteQuery... I can debug and see that Assignments exists, same for user and RoleDefBind.

I really don't understand what's missing. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this is a known issue in PS ClientRuntimeContext.Load method. Can you try the following?

```
foreach($item in $collListItem)
{
    $srcContext.Load($item)
    $srcContext.ExecuteQuery()

    $item.BreakRoleInheritance($false, $false);

    $RoleDefBind  = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($srcContext)
    $PermissionLevel = $srcContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("Lecture")

    #userToAdd
    $user = $srcWeb.SiteUsers.GetByLoginName("i:0#.w|domain\test");
    $srcContext.Load($user)
    $srcContext.ExecuteQuery()

    $RoleDefBind.Add($PermissionLevel)

    $Assignments = $item.RoleAssignments
    $srcContext.Load($Assignments)
    $srcContext.ExecuteQuery()


    $srcContext.Load($Assignments.Add($user,$RoleDefBind))
    $item.Update()
    $srcContext.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

You need to place the role assignments add within the context load method.

Comment: Not an "issue" that is how it works... but this is the correct answer none the less.

Comment: Thank you!
Yes the problem was that the Add should be inside the ctx.Load